# wfdb supported jvm 1.8.0_112 (using Octave and Windows)?

Tags: java, jvm, octave

I am trying to install [wfdb](https://www.physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/wfdb-app-matlab/) into octave on 64 bit Windows. I used the run of the mill installer to grab [octave 4.2](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/) and the [JRE 8u112](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html), both are the 64 bit versions. wfdb seems to install correctly and all the paths seem to be fine, but when I call

```
>> wfdbdemo
```

I get the following error:

```
error: Cannot load on unsupported JVM: Java 1.8.0_112
```

I am guessing that the newest version of JVM is too new for the wfdb toolbox? What version of the JVM should I get in order to run this?

Later...

OK, so the latest version o f wfdb on github does have the JVM 8 jar, so I snagged that. Now I get the error:

```
octave> wfdbdemo
error: javaMethod: could not find library or dependencies: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112\bin\client\jvm.dll
```

I've not seen any jre folder called client. Apparently the call to javaMethod (line 100 in wfdbloadlib.m) return this.

Later (again)...

So this is a bug that has to do with [Java](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8075410). I fiddled the registry so that it says 'server' instead of 'client' now, but I still get no joy. Now the problem is

```
octave> wfdbdemo
error: javaMethod: could not find library or dependencies: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

But, the path `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112\bin\server\jvm.dll` certainly is there and all things are 64 bit --- with the possible exception of the wfdb jar that comes with the source code on [github](https://github.com/ikarosilva/wfdb-app-toolbox/blob/master/mcode/wfdb-app-JVM8-0-9-10.jar).

Comment: In the end I solved this by downgrading to jdk 7, chaning 'client' to 'server' in the registry, and finally bu making sure that C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin was on my path env variable. Now it works.

Answer (score -1):

I also have difficulty as you:

> wfdb error: Cannot load WFDB JAR on unsupported JVM: Java 1.8.0_151
>   error: called from
>       wfdbloadlib at line 107 column 9
>       wfdb at line 11 column 10

Here is what did to resolve the error:

1. Install the [64-bit Windows JDK (i.e., 7u80)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html). This will result in two  folders in `C:\Program Files`:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80`

2. Setting the following Environment Variable in Windows:
   [image: Environment Variable]
3. Go to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin`, create the folder `client`, copy all files from `server` folder to `client`.
   [image: Copy files]
4. Then it should work as shown here:
   [image: Copy files]